# First ever Hollywood Color motion picture film?

Tags: american-cinema

Which is the first Hollywood Color motion picture film?

Comment: And why is really that downvote?

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia [Joan the Woman (1916)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joan_the_Woman), is the first american film to be released in colour.

However first in world is `Home footage` released in 1902 in Britain. Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_early_color_feature_films) for details.